# Can send large files only on local host

Tags: c#, forms, sockets

I'm trying to send files throw socket and did it...
The only thing went wrong is that I'm able to send large files ( above about 10 MB) only in localhost...
I can't transfer larger files in a real network...any help?

Client:

```
    byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
    byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
    byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
    fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
    fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
    fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(remoteHostIP, remoteHostPort);
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    networkStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.GetLength(0));
    networkStream.Close();
```

Server:

```
    try
    {
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(port);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (handlerSocket.Connected)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(handlerSocket);
            int thisRead = 0;
            int blockSize = 1024;
            Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[blockSize];
            lock (this)
                {
                    string folderPath = @"c:\";
                    handlerSocket.Receive(dataByte);
                    int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataByte, 0);
                    fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte, 4, fileNameLen);
                    Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(folderPath + fileName);
                    fileStream.Write(dataByte, 4+fileNameLen,(1024-(4+fileNameLen)));
                    while (true)
                    {

                        thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, blockSize);
                        fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0,thisRead);
                        if (thisRead == 0)
                        break;
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();

                }

            if (NewFileRecieved != null)
            {
                NewFileRecieved(this, fileName);
            }
            handlerSocket = null;
        }
    }

    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: Simply a suggestion, you should look into WCF services. You can easily create a method that receive a filestream. i have sent files in excess of 1.5 gig and the whole server app barely takes 30 min to code and setup. Also the WCF can send you back this data obviously. Big advantage is the WCF run at much lower level on a server as compared to a running EXE in the background of a locked session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this sounds like it could be tackled by modifying your app.config (or web.config) file. there's an entry that can be amended along the lines of:

```
<configuration>
...
    <system.web>

      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
      ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where `maxRequestLength` is the max file length in KB. fuller explanations can be found at:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-uploading-large-files.html

http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/large_files_iis_asp_net

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/web-configuration-setting-in-Asp-Net-to-post-larger-file/

**[Edit] -** as you can see from the comments below, this actual answer didn't resolve the issue, rather a nod towards using async sockets api brought a resolution. the full article that helped can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2014/01/10/sample-of-jan-9th-how-to-transfer-large-size-file-with-asynchronous-sockets-api-in-net.aspx

Comment: I can't find app.config!
should I add it manually?(It's a form)

Comment: lol -laughing at the downvote given by some hit and run :). as for your question, you may have to add this manually, tho potentially the solution may lie elsewhere of course - obviously quite difficult to guess based on the info (i gave it a shot, but was obvs not to the .net mega gods' pleasing -:))

Comment: you could also consider asynchronous operations as suggested here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2014/01/10/sample-of-jan-9th-how-to-transfer-large-size-file-with-asynchronous-sockets-api-in-net.aspx let me know if this helps...

Comment: OMG! asynchronous operations are magical!it worked - thanks man

Comment: yes, i live 75% of my life inside httpclient async methods -so much so that when my wife now asks me a question, I immediately respond with `Wait()` -lol

Comment: .. also, let me add the fact that the async methods resolved your issue as anyone else visiting the question will have to read the comments otherwise